# Parsing a field and list of people from Excel files

Tags: c#, .net, excel, regex

I'm trying to parse Excel (.xls, .xlsx) files. The structure of files is the same except for the amount of the records.

- I need to parse the industry. In this case it is "FinTech". Due to the fact that it is in one cell, I guess I have to use a regex expression such as `^Industry: (.*)$`?
- It has to find which row/column the list of the people starts and put it into a `IEnumerable<Person>`. It could use the following regex expressions.

  - `Number` always consists of 6 digits. `^[0-9]{6}$`
  - `Name` consists of at least two words where each one of them starts with a capital letter. `^([a-zA-Z]+\s?\b){2,}$`

A test .xlsx file can be found here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15SR04cHXgGLWe0cuOOuuB5vUZigebh96/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112418126731411268789&rtpof=true&sd=true.

```
List of people      
Normal condition        
Industry: FinTech       

#   Number  Name
1   226250  Zain Griffiths
2   226256  Michael Houghton
3   226259  Hugo Willis Johnson
4   226264  Anna-Maria Rose
```

### The actual question

First of all, I'm not completely sure if my regex expressions are correct. I was only able to display the rows and the columns but I'm not sure how to actually parse the *industry* and the list of the people into a `IEnumerable<Person>`. So how do I do that?

### Snippet

```cs
// Program.cs
var excel = new ExcelParser();
var sheet1 = excel.Import(@"a.xlsx");

Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
for (var i = 0; i < sheet1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < sheet1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        var cell = sheet1.Rows[i][j].ToString()?.Trim();

        Console.Write($"Column: {cell} | ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();

// ExcelParser.cs
public sealed class ExcelParser
{
    public ExcelParser()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    }

    public DataTable Import(string filePath)
    {
        // does file exist?
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        // .xls or .xlsx allowed
        var extension = new FileInfo(filePath).Extension.ToLowerInvariant();
        if (extension is not (".xls" or ".xlsx"))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        // read .xls or .xlsx
        using var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);

        var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
            {
                UseHeaderRow = false
            }
        });

        // Sheet1
        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The structure of files is the same except for the amount of the records

As long as the table is structured (or semi-structured), you can state one/two simple assumptions and parse the tables based on these assumptions, and in case the structure is not following the assumptions, you will return false (throw exception, etc..).

Actually, designing `regex`s to parse the table is kind of assumptions encoding.. I just want to *Keep it simple*, So, Based on the problem statement, here are my assumptions:

1. There will be a `"industry"` (or `"industry:"`, call `.ToLower()`) string in a separate cell (regex will do nothing more than finding such a string), and industry's name will be in the same cell.<sup>[1]</sup>
2. First person's name will be next to the first 6-digits-number cell.<sup>[2]</sup>

Here is the code

```
public (string industryName, List<string> peopleNames) ParseSheet(DataTable sheet1)
{
    // 1. Get Indices of industry cell and first Name in people names..

    var industryCellIndex = (-1, -1, false);
    var peopleFirstCellIndex = (-1, -1, false);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < sheet1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < sheet1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            // .ToLower() added
            var cell = sheet1.Rows[i][j].ToString()?.Trim().ToLower();
            if (cell.StartsWith("industry"))
            {
                industryCellIndex = (i, j, true);
                break;
            }

            // the name after the first 6-digits number cell will be the first name in people records
            if (cell.Length == 6 && int.TryParse(cell, out _))
            {
                peopleFirstCellIndex = (i, j + 1, true);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (industryCellIndex.Item3 && peopleFirstCellIndex.Item3)
            break;
    }

    if (!industryCellIndex.Item3 || !peopleFirstCellIndex.Item3)
    {
        // throw new Exception("Excel file is not normalized!");
        return (null, null);
    }

    // 2. retrieve the desired data

    var industryName = sheet1.Rows[industryCellIndex.Item1][industryCellIndex.Item2]
                       .Replace(":", ""); // will do nothing if there were no ":"

    industryName = industryName.Substring(industryName.IndexOf("indusrty") + "indusrty".Length);
    var peopleNames = new List<string>();
    var colIndex = peopleFirstCellIndex.Item2;
    for (var rowIndex = peopleFirstCellIndex.Item1;
         rowIndex < sheet1.Rows.Count;
         rowIndex++)
    {
        peopleNames.Add(sheet1.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString()?.Trim());
    }

    return (industryName, peopleNames);
}
```

---

[1] If this assumption needs some editing (like: the indusrty name might be the next cell that has `"industry"` string), the idea still the same.. you can consider this in parsing.

[2] And, for example, after the "#" cell by 2 columns and 1 row.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The first assumption is kinda wrong because "Industry: FinTech" is in one cell. I guess it has to be regex parsed.